# Change Static Variable Scope

Tags: c++

I have in one C++ class a definition of static variable:

```
static SomeType MyClass::StaticVariable;
```

In another class I want to use this variable without MyClass prefix. Can I do that? How?

Comment: You can derive from the class where the variable is declared.

Comment: Why would you want to change scope - if you do not want scope make it global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a reference:

```
class MyOtherClass {
    static SomeType &StaticVariable = MyClass::StaticVariable;
    // ...
}
```

You will have to ensure that you don't try to reference `MyOtherClass::StaticVariable` before `MyClass::StaticVariable` has been constructed (at program startup).

Comment: And how is that not using `MyClass::`?

Comment: Because you can then use `StaticVariable` inside `MyOtherClass` without using the `MyClass::` qualifier every time you use it. If that doesn't satisfy the question, then perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: But you have just used it in a first place — that's cheating.

Comment: @VladLazarenko: To be honest, I understand the same from the question, he does not want to use the scope operator on the *use* of the variable. Whether I would recommend this or your approach is a different question (I would recommend neither: it is a member of the original class, and it should be accessed as such, any other thing is just obfuscating code)

Comment: Totally agree with you on this one, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that only if that "another class" is derived from `MyClass` and `StaticVariable` has either public or protected visibility. Alternatively, you can move that member variable to some other scope or declare a reference/pointer and point it to that variable so that later you have to do less typing.